# what could be the firewalld(RHEL7) equivalent command

Tags: iptables, firewalld, rhel7

what could be the firewalld(RHEL7) equivalent command of "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firewall-cmd --add-port=5666/tcp --permanent; firewall-cmd --reload`

this information is easily obtainable via `man firewall-cmd` or via the documentation available [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD)